# Shifting between XML schemas and C# classes in a sensible fashion

Tags: c#, xml

A .NET/C# system receives XML messages for processing and further transmission.

Since working directly on XML documents would be very inconvenient, it is necessary to deserialize the message to a C# object and then serialize just before delivery.

Up until now this has been done with Microsoft's XSD tool (xsd.exe) and it gets the job done, but poorly. The tool is old and buggy and generates outrageous class names and code representations of the various XML schema constructs.

Are there better ways to accomplish this in .NET, or should I go a whole other way about it?

Comment: Are you wanting to generate a class based on the XML dynamically or do you know what fields are coming in from the XML?

Comment: Nothing dynamic. The XML schemas are static so the classes are only generated once.

Answer (score 3):

Unless there is an insane amount of properties, or the classes are changing on the fly, I just hand-write a POCO to handle deserialization. It is a bit of up-front investment, but if these objects are being used I like to have my naming conventions, etc., in place.

Comment: +1 same here.  I rarely generate them unless it's a ridiculously huge doc

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Visual Studio (I'm guessing this is likely), then check out [xsd2code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/).

I haven't used it in a while though so my memory might be a bit fuzzy, but it may just be a VS plugin wrapper around XSD.exe.  Give it a shot though.